# How to run shtml include in php

Tags: php, shtml

I have dozens of .shtml files on the server which include this statement to include `.inc` files:

```
 <!--#include virtual="../v4/rightmenu.inc" -->
```

This is exactly how it shows on the source which is working just fine.

I am wondering whether I can run this on my php code without changing it since the current files has this kind of inclusion a lot and I don't want to mess with a lot of code like this one.

I just don't want to change it to something like `<?php include "../v4/rightmenu.inc"; ?>`

Comment: SHTML was nice in its day, but you're basically trying to keep the stone age alive. Come into the 90s... we have cookies.

Comment: That's why you downvoted it? If I can, I could but I am dealing with hundred of pages and I don't want to spend my whole life to change them.

Comment: You could write an rewrite rule (mod_rewrite/htaccess) to pass all those .shtml files through one php file, which in turn looks for/and parses  #include statements in the requested file?!

Comment: @Yoshi: I didn't get that, can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I didn't do the downvote. That was already there when I left my comment. I only downvote things that are obviously outright wrong. You've just got a different opinion on this, which is not "wrong". But again, endure a little short-term pain right now and fix your files, and then you won't have to deal with this again in the future.

Comment: I second that. It seems this kind of change could be done relatively successfully with a simple regex (unless you have quotes in your filenames or nested HTML comments). Just out of curiosity - what made you switch from the server capable of SSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to route all requests to `.shtml` files through a single php file. For exapmle: _includeParser.php

A very rough sketch of such a file could be:

```
/**
 * This function should return the contents of the included file
 */
function getIncludeFileContents($match) {
    list (, $file) = $match;
    // return something for $file
}

/**
 * This function should return a php-readable path for the initially requested .shtml file
 */
function getRealpath($uri) {
  // return the real path of the requested uri
}

// Map the requested uri to file
// 'REDIRECT_URL' could be something different for your configuration, have a look at the $_SERVER array
// to get the correct value if something fails here
$realpath = getRealpath($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']); 

// parse each include statement
// the regex pattern here could need some tweaking
$output = preg_replace_callback(
  '@<!--#include virtual="(.+?)" -->@i',
  'getIncludeFileContents',
  file_get_contents($realpath)
);

// output the final contents
echo $output;
```

Of course a solution like this could be optimized by some caching or other methods.

Comment: What is the point in doing this replace dynamically at every request?

Comment: @Krab The same point as if you include a php-file. Reusability. For what other reasons would you put chunks of code/text whatever in different files?

Comment: No, I meant what's the benefit here over replacing the #include directive by `<?php include` or `<? echo file_get_contents` once for all?

Comment: And if preg is greedy (which I think it is), your regexp won't work if there would be another HTML comment ending by `" -->` after the #include. Maybe another #include. Instead of `.+`, you meant `[^"]+`.

Comment: @Kran ah! Of course that's a possibility. Problem is, That The Server would need be configurated to pass .shtml files to the php interpreter. About the regex, i Didn't meant this example to be usable as is. I just tried to sketch the idea.

Comment: Sure. Or they could be renamed. Ad regex - I didn't meant any offense. I was just pointing out a problem with regexes. They are not well readable and you see only what you want to see.

Comment: @Kran That could be a SEO problem.

Comment: @Yoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1019/discussion-between-krab-and-yoshi)