# error status message 403 to 423

Tags: apache, .htaccess

how would I change the default `403 forbidden` with a `423 locked` instead,
 when denying someone in htaccess.?

example, usually when you use `deny from` in htaccess, apache would serve a `403 forbidden` error.
is there a way to  set what error message is actually served in place of the `403 forbidden`?

I have not tried this, but im thinking maybe by defining custom error messages in htaccess might work,
for example,

```
ErrorDocument 403 /path/423.shtml
```

But something tells me my server would over ride that by default and still use the `403 error`.
and no, i do not have shell access or access to the apache install files.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you need a script or something to set the header response. Using the `ErrorDocument` by itself will still cause the server to return a **403 Forbidden**, eventhough the content returned will be what's in `/path/423.shtml`. You can use php or something to override that. So using the error document:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /path/423.php
```

Then in the `423.php` file:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 423 Locked");

// whatever other content you want returned
?>
```

Comment: ,if i am presuming right, in your example id be using a php file as an error page.instead of my shtml page. I have other code in use in the shtml page that i doubt would work in a php file as is.like the variables to show the users ip address and browser information and a meta refresh redirect.so im not certain if a php file would be a good idea or not.

Comment: @TheFuz There's 2 ways, you can include php in the shtml, or have the shtml be loaded by the php script. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839272/how-to-include-php-file-in-shtml-pages or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537674/how-to-run-shtml-include-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to do it "pure" (without PHP or Perl code) you will need to use mod_rewrite and utilize the [R=XXX] which means redirect and XXX is the code you want to use, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: so using the `[R=XXX]` with my example in the question, how would i go about getting it to work with `[R=423,L]` so it redirects from the default `403` to the new `423` sorry im not much of a code guru.

Comment: @TheFuz mod_rewrite can send a specific request to a response code using the `R` flag, but it can't intercept already outgoing 403 responses and change them (can be 403 for any reason, like not having the ability to view directory indexes).

Comment: @Jon Lin, thanks, can the `R flag` be used for any reference?. or just system error messages. i have a few custom error pages like `bots.shtml`, `spam.shtml`. would `[R=bots]` or `[R=spam]` work same way as the normal error status's ?

Comment: @TheFuz If you want to load "bots", then `RewriteRule ^some-pattern$ /bots.html [L,R=123]`, where "123" is the response code. Not all of them will work, and its behavior is not very well documented